# RadGrid Ignores Negatives While Sorting

Tags: telerik, telerik-grid, radgrid

I have a Telerik RadGrid that contains the following columns:

`Item Name, Price, Price Change, % of Change`

All of the three trailing columns contain decimal data. Price column contains all positive decimals while the other two contain both negatives and positives.

Sorting by `Price` and `Price Change` works fine but when I try to sort by the `% of Change` column, RadGrid seems to ignore the negations. The output of the column is something like:

```
 0.00
 0.21
-0.39
-0.55
 0.63
```

Note, that the `Price Change` column contains similar data but when sorting, it does not treat negative numbers as positives.

Any ideas why this is happening or how it can be resolved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turned out to be my data source that was converting the `% of Change` after calculation into a string type. I was using `FORMAT(myformula, 2)` to convert the percentage into fixed format with two decimal places. Upon using `CONVERT(myformula, DECIMAL(11,2)` the column sorting seems to be working fine.